# How to display an alert on mouseover events

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, have functionality whereby mouseover will change the div to red upon placing the mouse over. I would like to change this to have an alert pop up instead, which displays the text held within the div.

I have tried calling a function to call the alert

```
<img onmouseover='getAlert(this)' class='calPicSmile' src= 'img/" + calImg + ".png' height= '20' width= '20'>
```

as well as

```
document.getElementsByClassName("calPicSmile").onmouseover = function() {getAlert()};
function getAlert(){
  alert('test');
}
```

```js
if (counter == day && month == curMonth && year == curYear) {

  htmlContent += "<td class='dayNow alert' id='" + counter + monthIDName + "'  onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' " + "onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"; this.style.color=\"#FF0000\"'>" + counter + "<img class='calPicSmile' src= 'img/" + calImg + ".png' height= '20' width= '20'>" + "</td>";

} else {

  htmlContent += "<td class='monthNow alert' id='" + counter + monthIDName + "' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"'" + " onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'>" + counter + "<img class='calPicSmile' src= 'img/" + calImg + ".png' height= '20' width= '20'>" + "</td>";

}
```

Comment: There's an error in your code. It doesnt work at all. You should fix it then we can help with your question.`"Uncaught ReferenceError: counter is not defined"`

Comment: it does work, but I didnt want to supply the entire code. Will update now

Comment: why don't you update your code at jsbin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without you having to post full code, are you trying to achieve something like this?

```js
function getAlert(image) {
  alert('Here\'s an alert!')
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover='getAlert(this)' class='calPicSmile' src='https://images-production.global.ssl.fastly.net/uploads/photos/file/117262/michae-scott-quotes-5.jpg?auto=compress&crop=top&fit=clip&h=500&q=55&w=698' height='100' width='140'>
```

Comment: This is what I want, however, it seems to be an issue with Framework7 (Which is what I'm using to create my app). Possibly, mouseover is the wrong thing to use, though it does work with making divs red

Answer (score 3):

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
function Alert(e){
 alert(e.target.innerText);
};

</script>

<div onmouseover="Alert(event)">Hover Me</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this you want?